# I installed Ubuntu 20 on a Lenovo Thinkpad P50 - now it goes into memtest when I start the machine, and freezes, refuses to leave memtest

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

Is there a way I can skip memtest?
Or install Ubuntu in a way that it skips memtest?

I've read that Ubuntu should work fine on a Lenovo Thinkpad P50, but its not going smoothly for me. Install worked just fine, but now its won't boot into main homescreen - just stuck on memtest and frozen.

Thank you anyone and everyone for your help!

Comment: What are you calling "memtest"? What is "Ubuntu 20"? There is no such release. Where did you get the installer?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - I downloaded the installer from the Ubuntu web site. memtest86+ is part of the release.

Comment: Please correct your question, Ubuntu products that use the *year* format (*snap* only) are different to the *year.month* (use *deb* packages by default) and your question as written mixes two different systems (snap-only-containerized release & desktop-server release). (*You can edit your own questions*).  If you're talking POST (power-on-self-test*) that is done in uEFI/BIOS config; Ubuntu does not invoke a memtest feature (there are limits to when it'll run anyway, not being available for uEFI setups anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing right now.  I found this on a quick DDG search:

https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/thinkpad_p43s_p53s_ubuntu_installation_whitepaper_v1.0.pdf

Check your BIOS/UEFI settings with the instructional above, then try re-installing.  Let me know if that works and any other problems you're having please!

That got my OS up and running on the P50 but I'm still having browser problems.  I think my problem is a problem with the NVIDIA Quadro M1000M, although the whitepaper addresses how to install the proper driver.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu... but I installed a minimum install... and it worked, probably because it didn't install memtest86+!